# DataGridView Show Complete Headers And Content

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

[image]

I want this datagridview to Show Complete Headers and Row Content. If size exceed the Grid size it should then display a ScrollBar to view the complete cells.

I tried and Some similar instructions but couldn't get the desired result

```
dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
```

Comment: You'd be better off increasing the surface area of the form so that it can show more information, or reducing the amount of information being displayed.

Comment: I have seen forms having scrollbars to get the desired data to display. Can't I do that ?

I have multiple forms being displayed at the same time so i have tried to adjust the positions according. Can't increase the size in this casee

Comment: Do you want a horizontal scrollbar for the whole grid?

Comment: Yes A Horizontal scrollbar will be good.!

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.scrollbars?view=net-5.0), and give each of your columns a fixed width.